# Can we set the dropdown list for the textfield to select an option in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

I need a textfield which has an dropdown list to select an option from that.Is there any possible chances to do that in Iphone sdk?

Guys I need a quick help from ur side.

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a UIPickerView instead of a dropdown list.

Edit: i missed the text field part. You are emulating a combo box.

You can use a picker + text field, and fill the text field from the pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent delegat method

Edit2: There are some S/O questions about this already - related to UIPickerView bugs

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
[self gotodropdown];
}

-(void)dropdown
{

if(dropDownView==nil && ([copyListOfItems count] > 0))
        {
            dropDownView = [[DropDownView alloc] initWithArrayData:copyListOfItems  heightTableView:200 paddingTop:0 paddingLeft:0 paddingRight:0 refView:textField animation:BOTH openAnimationDuration:2 closeAnimationDuration:0.5 ];
            dropDownView.delegate = self;
            [dropDownView openAnimation];
            [self addSubview:dropDownView.view];
        }

}


//dropdown.m

- (id)initWithArrayData:(NSMutableArray *)data  heightTableView:(CGFloat)tHeightTableView paddingTop:(CGFloat)tPaddingTop paddingLeft:(CGFloat)tPaddingLeft paddingRight:(CGFloat)tPaddingRight refView:(UIView*)rView animation:(AnimationType)tAnimation openAnimationDuration:(CGFloat)openDuration closeAnimationDuration:(CGFloat)closeDuration {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        //array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//[array addObjectsFromArray:data];
        self.array = [data retain];
        NSLog(@"ARRAYIS:%@",data);
        self.refView = rView;

        self.paddingTop = tPaddingTop;

        self.paddingLeft = tPaddingLeft;

        self.paddingRight = tPaddingRight;

        self.heightTableView = tHeightTableView;

        self.open = openDuration;

        self.close = closeDuration;

        CGRect refFrame = refView.frame;

        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(refFrame.origin.x-paddingLeft,refFrame.origin.y+refFrame.size.height+paddingTop,refFrame.size.width+paddingRight, heightTableView);

        self.view.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

        self.view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);

        self.view.layer.shadowOpacity =1.0f;

        self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
        animationType = tAnimation;



    }

    return self;

}
```

use tableview delegate for further details